# onBlur is not working on TextArea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on Value Formating based on input on Form Fields, for this purpose i'm using this selector

```
jQuery( "input[name*='socialtag']" ).blur(function() {
     var value = jQuery(this).val();
    alert(value);
 });
```

i also use alternative like this:

```
jQuery(document).on('blur', 'input[name*=\'socialtag\']', function () {
    var value = jQuery(this).val();
    alert(value);
});
```

Both are working for the input field, but it's not working for the TextArea field. Is there something i miss ?

Comment: A textarea's CSS selector is `textarea`, not `input`. You probably want `input[name*=\'socialtag\'], textarea[name*=\'socialtag\']`

Comment: @blex, Be sure to add this as an answer to the question so you get credit for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A textarea's CSS selector is `textarea`, not `input`.

So, to select both, you can do this:

```
jQuery(document).on('blur', 'input[name*=\'socialtag\'], textarea[name*=\'socialtag\']', function () {
    var value = jQuery(this).val();
    alert(value);
});
```

How CSS selectors work *(the basics)*:

- Selectors that start with a `#` select an element with a certain ID.
- Selectors that start with a `.` select elements with a certain class.
- Selectors that have nothing in front of them select elements with a certain tag name (ie `div`, `span`, `input`, `textarea`...).

Answer (score 1):

In HTML, TextArea is a TAG itself. It's not a type of input field. Hence trying to find an input with that name won't work. Try this :

```
jQuery( "textarea[name*='socialtag']" ).blur(function() {
    var value = jQuery(this).val();
    alert(value);
});
```